# Angular 8 custom framework

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, angular8, nexus

I wanted to design and develop a framework on top of Angular 8/9 which should serve for multiple applications which can share common code across all the applications.

This application serves for various countries, the rules from country to country may same or differ.

**UI-Components**: custom UI components which is exposed as node module, In future which can be upgraded and published to all the apps.
**Core** : which should have common, core, abstract code for all the applications.

**Country-1 code** : Country-1 is Implementation of Core, which will reuse and extend them where ever required.

**Country-N code** : Country-N is Implementation of Core, which will reuse and extend them where ever required.

I have below structure in consideration but i wanted to parameterize by country, i mean on generation dist, the respective dist should not package with other country code.

https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

The design should be close for modification and open for extension.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVmy0.png)
I appreciate your response.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand completely. Are you trying to create different configuration builds for each country and create different `/dist` outputs each time you want to deploy?

Comment: Yes each country should get deployed separately, which should share common code and support Polymorphism in html, components, services across all layers.   @Superiom

Comment: Since you are going with different builds for each deployment (according to me that will make your life more difficult), you can make a configuration build that will copy specific files by a passed configuration parameter. For example: `ng build --prod --configuration country1`. In angular.json you can specify which files to be copied over.

Comment: @Superiom - Yes i have done same at server side using maven(Parameterized build by passing country code). Can you please share more information to achieve this.   
My intention also includes to separate the version control from country to country. where country specific developer may not access to core/common & other country code.

Comment: I assume you will have different folders for each country implementation. Hence, you can update `angular.json` production configurations for each country. For example: `configurations: { country1: { scripts: { input: path to script, output: output path}}}`. With the command `ng build --prod --configuration country1`, the `/dist` folder should include the script files for that country. I can post an example of a script as an answer if you want?

Comment: @Superiom Yes please. My intention also includes to separate the version control from country to country. where country specific developer may not access to core/common & other country code. how do we achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain the tags here (without me leaving the page to an outside link)?  Are they the resources you are using/want to use/have at your disposal?

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot post an this much characters as a comment, I am posting this as an answer. It might not be exactly what you need, but I think it is a good starting point.

If you have the following project structure

```
--app
  --components
    --component1
      --country1
      --country2
    --component2
      --country1
      --country2
```

And if you want to have different production builds for each country, you want to update the `angular.json` file so that it will include specific file/folder transfer configurations for each country. For example, the production build has this configuration:

```
"production": {
   "fileReplacements": [
       {
           "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
           "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
       }
    ],
    ...
}
```

Then you will need to add the country specific configurations:

```
"country1": {
   "assets": [
       {
           "input": "src/app/components/component1/country1",
           "output": "components/component1"
       },
       {
           "input": "src/app/components/component2/country1",
           "output": "components/component2"
       }
   ]
    ...
}
```

Then you can run a production build with the command:

`ng build --prod --configuration country1`

This will copy the script files in the assets folder and simply load them from there. I think this will copy over the scripts as they are (without minification etc.).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Looks project structure is not how am looking like. each country code should reside in separate repository. configuring each and every component in build file is overhead on peer developers.

Comment: If you plan to publish each country-specific set of components as a separate node module, I believe each package name should be included in your `package.json` file. I don't see any other way with the experience that I have.

Comment: is it possible to include angular 8 project in other angular project?